# php: loop through json array

Tags: php, json

I have a json array:

```
[
    {
        "var1": "9",
        "var2": "16",
        "var3": "16"
    },
    {
        "var1": "8",
        "var2": "15",
        "var3": "15"
    }
]
```

How can I loop through this array using php?

Comment: Use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert it to a PHP array.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Set the second function parameter to true if you require an associative array

<strike>Some versions of php require a 2nd paramter of true if you require an associative array</strike>

```
$json  = '[{"var1":"9","var2":"16","var3":"16"},{"var1":"8","var2":"15","var3":"15"}]';
$array = json_decode( $json, true );
```

Comment: There's no version specific reference to the second `assoc` argument

Answer (score 102):

Decode the JSON string using `json_decode()` and then loop through it using a regular loop:

```
$arr = json_decode('[{"var1":"9","var2":"16","var3":"16"},{"var1":"8","var2":"15","var3":"15"}]');

foreach($arr as $item) { //foreach element in $arr
    $uses = $item['var1']; //etc
}
```

Comment: +1 for this. it is exactly what I was trying to do, however the lack of the true for the associative array was giving me an error.

Answer (score 46):

First you have to decode your json :

```
$array = json_decode($the_json_code);
```

Then after the json decoded you have to do the foreach

```
foreach ($array as $key => $jsons) { // This will search in the 2 jsons
     foreach($jsons as $key => $value) {
         echo $value; // This will show jsut the value f each key like "var1" will print 9
                       // And then goes print 16,16,8 ...
    }
}
```

If you want something specific just ask for a key like this. Put this between the last foreach.

```
if($key == 'var1'){
 echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) to convert the JSON string to a PHP array, then use normal PHP array functions on it.

```
$json = '[{"var1":"9","var2":"16","var3":"16"},{"var1":"8","var2":"15","var3":"15"}]';
$data = json_decode($json);

var_dump($data[0]['var1']); // outputs '9'
```

Comment: This doesn't loop through the array tho. It just retrieves the first value?