# Passing JSON object to PHP with jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I have 3 different JSON objects I want to concatenate and send over to a PHP file with jQuery AJAX. I can retrieve the JSON object in the PHP file, but cannot figure out how to loop through the results.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    //my 3 JSON objects:

    var json_obj_1{
        "test1_key":"test1_val",
        "test2_key":"test2_val",
        "test3_key":"test3_val"
    }

    var json_obj_2{
        "test4_key":"test4_val"
    }

    var json_obj_3{
        "json_arr":[
              {
                  "test1":"test2",
                  "test3":"test4"
              }
         ]
    }

   //concat these to send over to the PHP file:
   var my_json_obj = json_obj_1.concat(json_obj_2);

   //I found if I didn't stringify obj_3 they didn't concatenate for some reason
   my_json_obj = my_json_obj.concat(JSON.stringify(json_obj_3));


   //my_json_obj  now looks like this:

   {
        "test1_key":"test1_val",
        "test2_key":"test2_val",
        "test3_key":"test3_val"
   }
   {
        test4_key: test4_val
   }
   {
        "json_obj_3":[
            {"test1":"test2","test3":"test4"}
        ]
   }
```

Based on this question: [Sending JSON to PHP using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955017/sending-json-to-php-using-ajax), I don't stringify the final JSON object.

Here's the AJAX call to the PHP file:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'my_php_file.php',
        data: {my_json_data: my_json_obj},
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache:false,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            console.log('AJAX SUCCESS');
        }, 
        complete : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            console.log('AJAX COMPLETE');
        }
});
```

This is what it looks like when retrieved in my PHP file:

```
echo $_POST['my_json_data'];
//outputs:
{
    "test1_key":"test1_val",
    "test2_key":"test2_val",
    "test3_key":"test3_val"
}
{
     test4_key: test4_val
}
{
    "json_obj_3":[
        {"test1":"test2","test3":"test4"}
    ]
}
```

Here's where I run in to problems. I want to be able to loop through this in a foreach. From what I have read ([php: loop through json array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731242/php-loop-through-json-array)) I have to decode the JSON object. However when I do this and loop through the results I get: " PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ".

Even if I stringify the JSON object before sending it over to the PHP file I get the same problem. I have been banging my head against a brick wall for hours with this. Any help will be massively appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Solved:**

I was going wrong when concatenating my JSON objects following this question: [Merge two json/javascript arrays in to one array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384845/merge-two-json-objects-in-to-one-object). Instead I just put them together like so:

```
my_json_obj = '['+json_obj_1+','+json_obj_2+', '+JSON.stringify(json_obj_3)+']';
```

I then use json_decode in my PHP file which works a treat. http://json.parser.online.fr/ was invaluable in debugging my dodgy JSON. A great tool for JSON beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say you need to decode the JSON, but your JSON is not well formed so I think the decode function is failing which causes the foreach error.  There needs to be a , between objects, there's missing quotes around test4_val and it needs to be inside a singular object/array

You can check your JSON is wellformed at:-

http://json.parser.online.fr/

I think you want it to look more like:-

```
[{
"test1_key":"test1_val",
"test2_key":"test2_val",
"test3_key":"test3_val"
},
{
 "test4_key": "test4_val"
},
{
"json_obj_3":[
    {"test1":"test2","test3":"test4"}
]
}]
```

Comment: Thanks joep1978, for someone new to working with JSON pointing me to http://json.parser.online.fr/ was a great idea, solved a lot of problems.

Answer (score 3):

You should be stringifying the whole object, try the following:

```
var my_json_obj = json_obj_1;

$.each(json_obj_2, function(key,value){
    my_json_obj[key]=value;
});
$.each(json_obj_3, function(key,value){
    my_json_obj[key]=value;
});
```

Ajax request:

```
data: {my_json_data: JSON.stringify(my_json_obj)},
```

PHP:

```
print_r(json_decode($_POST['my_json_data']));
```