# Is this json format?

Tags: php, json

I am getting this output:

```
{"params":{"2":true,"3":true}}
```

I have printed this as (at PHP side):

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
        print($data);
```

I want to use that 2 and 3 values using loop at PHP side. But as I am trying, it is not json format (its doubt). So how can i use these values using loop?

Comment: Looks like valid json, show the code you have that is failing, eg the loop

Comment: what is the code with which you are trying?

Comment: foreach($data as $d)
  {
   echo $d->params;
  }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731242/php-loop-through-json-array

Google search failure

Comment: json is just a string in php, to use it as a data structure, you must convert it to an array or object with `json_decode()`

Comment: Use this tool = http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: Did you notice, here square brackets are not present, still it is json? I don't think so! If it is not json, how can I decode it with json_decode ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$j='{"params":{"2":true,"3":true}}';

$decoded=json_decode($j,1);

print "<pre>\n";
print_r($decoded);
print "</pre>\n";
```

The second parameter of json_decode() is

> 'assoc' - When TRUE, returned object s will be converted into
>   associative array

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$json='{"params":{"2":true,"3":true}}';

$params=json_decode($json, true)['params'];

foreach ($params as $k =>$v){
    echo $k . ' is ' .  var_export($v, true) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

output:

```
2 is true
3 is true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data='{"params":{"2":true,"3":true}}';
$decoded=json_decode($data,1);
        foreach ($decoded as $key => $param)
        {
            foreach ($param as $user_id => $value)
            {
                    echo $user_id;
            }
        }
```

It gives me output:

```
 2 3
```

(as I expected).