# loop foreach $var value

Tags: php, json, loops, variables

I have a json file and i need a loop for echo the contnent for each id value

like this:

```
{
"dati": [
   {
    "id": 96984,
    "sottotitolo": "test sottotitolo",
    "img": "https://sdsds.com",
    "url": "asdsa.com",
    "stato": "IT",
    "regione": "IT.08",
   }

   { 
    "id": 24543,
    "sottotitolo": "test sottotitolo2",
    "img": "https://sdsds.com",
    "url": "asdsa.com",
    "stato": "IT",
    "regione": "IT.08",
  }
]
}
```

to something like this:

```
<div id"96984"> <h3>test sottotitolo</h3> ......... </div> <div id"24543"> <h3>test sottotitolo2</h3> ......... </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php: loop through json array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731242/php-loop-through-json-array)

Comment: json_decode then loop through it is the summary of the answer you're seeking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$data = file_get_contents("/path/to/your/file.json");
$dataArray = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($dataArray as $row){
    foreach ($row as $key => $value){
        switch ($key) {
            case 'id':
              echo  "<div> $value </div>";
            break;
            case 'sottotitolo':
              echo  "<h3> $value </h3>";
            break;
            case 'img':
              echo  "<img src=$value >";
            break;
           // ...
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i get a blank page whit this code