# Break after a specific word in (pre) tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, curl, styling

I have a website, which gets information from another website. However the information on that website is all in a `<pre>` tag.

So when I post it on my website, it is all in a `<pre>` tag as well.

My question: How can I style a `<pre>` element? 
For example: I get the word *room* multiple times, and I want a `<br>` after that.

The code I use to get information from the website:

```
<?php
    // create a new cURL resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set URL and other appropriate options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    // copy the handle
    $ch2 = curl_copy_handle($ch);

    // grab URL (http://www.example.com/) and pass it to the browser
    curl_exec($ch2);

    // close cURL resources, and free up system resources
    curl_close($ch2);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

example.com is my website from where I get data. It is a local thing, so no use in posting this right here now.

**EDIT:**

it's working now!

Code:

```
    $url = "http://10.132.185.226:9997/api/rooms";
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($content);
```

Then we loop through the results, and can get them one by one :)

Comment: replace the word 'room' with 'room<br>' wouldn't do it?

Comment: Can you include `<pre>` element containing text at Question ?

Comment: @randy How do i do that, if i all get it from 1 variable? 

guest271314 {"rooms":[{"name":"name1","meetings":[]},{"name":"name2","meetings":[]}}

Comment: Is your data JSON like you show there? Then use for-each loops to iterate over these keys and create your own string. That way you are in full control. I dont know php that well though, so i could only show you in JQuery or JS

Comment: It is indeed in Json @randy . Also do you have a example? Or explanation books? Since i don't know alot/anything about Json.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731242/php-loop-through-json-array

Comment: But i'm wondering. This won't work because the variable can be filled? Becuase it is a link from our agenda. So it can be filled. How will i show that?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for this.

```
JSON.stringify(variable, 0, 4)
```

[`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) applies linebreaks and indent to the string.

```js
var guest271314 = { "rooms": [{ "name": "name1", "meetings": [] }, { "name": "name2", "meetings": [] }] };
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(guest271314, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get your result, replace all the occurrences of the word along with a `<br>` tag.

For example: 
suppose `var result` stores the output that you got.

```
var alignedResult = result.replace(/room */g,"room <br>");
alignedResult = result.replace(/room. */g,"room. <br>");
alignedResult = alignedResult.replace(/room, */g, "room, <br>");
```

**Note:** I have replaced multiple times the word room to make sure that the format of the original is retained and also there are no leading white spaces at the beginning of the new line. Also, here other variants of *room* as in *Room* or *rOOm* will be missed out!

If you want to replace the word *rooms*, you can add further conditions to the above solution.

Comment: This is making sense. However 1 question. How do i get 'curl_exec($ch2);'   To become .result ?