# PHP iterate through array with dictionary

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, dictionary

Hi Im new to php and I have an array that looks like the following code.

```
 [ { "amount" : "204", "order" : "15", "customer": "12"}, { "amount" : "208", "order" : "17", "customer": "18"},{ "amount" : "300", "order" : "15", "customer": "19"} ]
```

How do I iterate and get all the amounts ? Tried using foreach and ended up with and invalid argument where I used .

```
   $xabo = [ { "amount" : "204", "order" : "15", "customer": "12"}, { "amount" : "208", "order" : "17", "customer": "18"},{ "amount" : "300", "order" : "15", "customer": "19"} ] 
   foreach($xabo as $denge){
   print_r $denge['amount'];
   }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php: loop through json array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731242/php-loop-through-json-array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a JSON encoded array. You need to define it as a string and decode it. For print_r you also need brackets.

```
 $xabo_str = '[ { "amount" : "204", "order" : "15", "customer": "12"}, { "amount" : "208", "order" : "17", "customer": "18"},{ "amount" : "300", "order" : "15", "customer": "19"} ]';
 $xabo = json_decode($xabo_str, true);
 foreach($xabo as $denge){
   print_r($denge['amount']);
 }
```

The true in json_decode makes sure that you only get arrays. That way you can access the keys with the `array['key']` syntax.

Comment: "JSON encoded array" This isn't an encoded array. It's a simple JSON string, not an array. it is encoded if you actually use *json_encode()* to convert it back though.