# How to loop JSON data?

Tags: php

I have to make a loop from number 1 to the last line + echo,

How can this be done?

```
$api = file_get_contents($url);
$api = json_decode($api, true);

foreach.. // i need to loop from 1 - until the last
echo $api['available_channels']['1']["live"] .";
}
```

Comment: You should add your Json to question

Comment: show some more details for $api  last, means print  value of $api

Comment: If you want to isolate columnar data from your array, there is a dedicated function for that.  Please post sample input to give your question context.  If you are doing something specific with the values (other than just echoing), you should describe your actual task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php: loop through json array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731242/php-loop-through-json-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a punt, something like the following (untested as no sample data):

```
$api = file_get_contents($url);
$api = json_decode($api, true);

foreach($api['available_channels'] as $channel) {
    echo $channel["live"];
}
```